# Error al regresar datos desde PHP a Javascript: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estoy haciendo un formulario y estoy usando fetch para mandar y recibir datos con PHP:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token `<` in JSON at position 0 at `fetch.then.res` (`app.js:15`)

Aquí mi código de `app.js`:

[image: app.js]

Archivo `inserta.php` (donde mando la cadena que quiero capturar en `app.js`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente es la función que estoy llamando para obtener la cadena:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué navegador usas? Abre la consola de depuración de red y mira qué te devuelve el servidor. Según parece hay HTML en la respuesta JSON. Por otro lado, por favor, copia y pega el código REAL y no captures imágenes. Es una mala práctica, nos dejamos la vista en ella y no nos ayuda a reproducir y arreglar tu problema.

Comment: Hola, estoy usando chrome. ¿A cúal consola de depuración de red te refieres?

Comment: Si pulsas Control+Mayúsculas+J se abrirá la consola, en la que tendrás la pestaña llamada "Network" que te ofrece información detallada de cada conexión realizada. Recarga la página y observa la petición XHR (`fetch()`). En particular dale a la pestaña "Response" tras pulsar en la petición.

Comment: Me regresa lo siguiente: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: chk in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/formulario/files/inserta.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
"Datos <br \/>111Oficina de Abogado General<p>Hola<\/p>"   Por lo que veo el problema está al enviar un check sin marcar.

Comment: He votado tu pregunta para quitarte el negativo que te habían dado y he redactado una explicación de tu problema y un par de soluciones posibles. Una a tu problema exacto y otra solución general para cualquier problema de depuración que tengas en un futuro.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que estás sufriendo es debido a que cuando no marcas la casilla de verificación cuyo `name="chk"` el valor `$_POST['chk']` no está definido, por lo que te lanzará una advertencia de índice no definido en la siguiente línea:

```
if ($_POST["chk"] == "")
{
  $chk = 0;
}
else
{
  $chk = 1;
}
```

Te recomiendo cambiarlo por:

```
if (empty($_POST["chk"])) {
  $chk = 0;
} else {
  $chk = 1;
}
```

De esa manera no se mezclará código HTML del error con el JSON que debe entregarse.

Además, como sistema de protección contra mezcla de mensajes de advertencia o error **durante la fase de desarrollo**, te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente:

- Hacer uso de [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) al comienzo del script PHP para guardar este tipo de mensajes en un almacén temporal y no sean enviados al cliente hasta que lo decidamos.
- Usar [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_end_clean) justo antes del `echo json_encode()` para descartar la salida del almacén temporal y enviar al cliente únicamente el `echo`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
/* Comenzamos a guardar todo en un almacén temporal */
ob_start();
/* Hacemos nuestro trabajo */
/* ... */
/* Descartamos los mensajes de advertencia previos */
ob_end_clean();
/* Configuramos las cabeceras para los datos enviados */
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
/* Enviamos el JSON al cliente */
echo json_encode($ofi);
```

En producción no deberías tener ningún tipo de advertencia, deberías depurar cualquier caso que pudiera producirse o bien en vez de usar `ob_end_clean()` usar un [`ob_get_clean()`](http://php.net/ob_get_clean) y guardar los mensajes obtenidos a un archivo de log mediante `file_put_contents(..., FILE_APPEND)` o bien [`error_log()`](http://php.net/function.error_log).

```
<?php
/* Comenzamos a guardar todo en un almacén temporal */
ob_start();
/* Hacemos nuestro trabajo */
/* ... */
/* Enviamos al log los mensajes de advertencia */
error_log(ob_get_clean());
/* Configuramos las cabeceras para los datos enviados */
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
/* Enviamos el JSON al cliente */
echo json_encode($ofi);
```

PD: Usar `"$ofi"` en vez de `$ofi` es redundante (aunque equivalente). No envuelvas las variables entre comillas si sólo deseas usar su contenido.